# Reviewing code that is used to workaround a bug in third party tools/code etc

Tags: discussion, scope

As developers we sometimes come across bug in third part code / tools / stuff we can't change and so we write a hack/workaround or some other dirty piece of code.

Is the "hack" reviewable?
It matches everything in the FAQ (as I understand it) but its about working around broken code and often how "pretty" it makes my code look is irrelevant.

Specifically I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930304/metalsmith-static-site-pages-are-missing-metadata) about an issue I was having with an IDE + framework working together and posted how I worked around it. Even though I'm hoping for a non-hacky answer I think it could still be written better.

Answer (score 10):

I think the main criterion here should be "Do you want it to be good code?"  If so, it should be on-topic for review.

You should, of course, mention the rationale for the ugly code in the question, and state what is and isn't within your control.  It should be fair game for reviewers to answer with a completely different (and hopefully better) workaround.